# How to change image accordingly on Hover/Mouse enter On Any List Item using set State React

Tags: reactjs, use-state, setstate, mouseenter, mousehover

[Right Side i have list items on left i have picture area i want to change image accordingly when ever i hover list item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvtdv.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

[image]

Comment: I have typed same code but not getting result which I want.

Comment: Can you show it? @RajaNaseem